# Django - Pass object into custom form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a rating form field using the jquery code [here](http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/index.html)
So far I have it working fine but what I need to do is pass in a url based on the object I am trying to rate.  See line  `$.post("URL TO GO HERE", {rating: value}, function(db)` is code below.  The url would be something like `/rating/object_id` where object_id would be the pk of the object I want to rate.  What is the best way to pass in a object id so I can use it.  Would I need to pass it into RatingField first and then pass it from there into StarWidget?

```
class StarWidget(widgets.Select):
    """
    widget to show stars which the user can click on to rate
    """
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('css/ui.stars.css',)
        }
        js = ('js/ui.stars.js',)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = super(StarWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)

        jquery = u"""
        <div id="stars-rating" class="rating_section">
            %s
            <span id="caption"></span>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#stars-rating").stars({
                inputType: "select",
                captionEl: $("#caption"),
                cancelShow: false,
                callback: function(ui, type, value)
                {
                    // Hide Stars while AJAX connection is active
                    $("#stars-rating").hide();
                    $("#loader").show();
                    $.post("URL TO GO HERE", {rating: value}, function(db)
                    {
                        $("#loader").hide();
                        $("#stars-rating").show();
                    }, "json");
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

        """ % (output)

        return mark_safe(jquery)

class RatingField(forms.ChoiceField):
    """
    rating field.  changes the widget and sets the choices based on the model
    """
    widget = StarWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RatingField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.label = "Rating:"
        self.initial = 3
        self.choices = Rating.RATING_CHOICES
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the built-in fields are done this way, but it's really not good practice to embed large amounts of HTML or JS into the Python code. Instead, create a separate template fragment which is rendered by the field's `render` method. You can pass in the object's ID for use in the template `{% url %}` function, or just pass in the entire URL via call to `reverse`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: what I am unsure of is how I can 'create a separate template fragment which is rendered by the field's render method'  I know how to create the fragment but not sure how to get it rendered by the widget render function.

Comment: @John: see section 'Rendering a template' in the Django Book: http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter04/

Comment: @André: I'm still not sure how to get the variable i.e. object id I am trying to rate, into the render function in the first place. Any advise on that please?